# Spring Security role not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Spring-Boot Security returning Forbidden 404 for request even when I have given proper authentication.

I am setting the below UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken to Security Context holder

[My UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n3RL.png) 
.

Below is my

1. Security Config class

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/seller/**").hasRole("SELLER")
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/consumer/**").hasRole("CONSUMER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

2. My user entity

```
package com.fresco.ecommerce.models;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5536306799835655715L;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Integer userId;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String username, String password, Set<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userId=" + userId + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", roles=" + roles
                + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles.stream().map(r -> new RoleGrantedAuthority(r.name())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I tried eveything. When I removed the hasRole i am able to hit the api.

I am new to Spring how can I debug where it is being forbidded.

Comment: 404 is not *Forbidden*, it is *Not Found*. What URL do you call? Show your request with headers. Show your Spring Security TRACE logs.